# "faire la plus peur" or "faire la plus de peur"

Tags: superlatifs

> 1. Qu'est-ce qui te fait la plus peur ?
> 2. Qu'est-ce qui te fait la plus **de** peur ?

Which sentence is correct? If we look at *faire peur* as an expression and want to modify the whole expression, then we should use the first option. But if we just want to modify the noun *peur*, then we should use the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the expression *faire peur* the noun *peur* is used without the definite article *la*.

> Traverser ce carrefour me fait peur.

In *ce qui te fais le plus peur*, *le plus* modifies the verbal phrase *faire peur* and not the noun *peur*, therefore it is considered neutral, i.e. neither masculine nor feminine, and in French neutral has the same form as the masculine.

> Qu'est-ce qui te fait le plus peur ?
>      Qu'est-ce qui te fait le plus de peur ? (this sounds rather awkward, but I can't really say it is not correct)

If you define *peur* then you can use the superlative on the noun, and thus *la plus* is used according to the gender of the noun because you compare it with other kinds of *peur(s)*.

> Qu'est-ce qui t'a fait la plus grande peur de ta vie ?
>   Connais-tu une plus grande peur que de te trouver face à face avec un lion ?

Comment: What's the explanation why we can use *le plus de peur*? It sounds almost like we are just modifying *peur* here.

Comment: @user11550 is your question about why *le* an not *la* or you we can say *le plus de peur* ? Actually *Qu'est-ce qui te fait le plus de peur ?* sounds rather awkward but I can't say it's not correct.

Comment: Ok thanks, that answered my question.

Comment: @user11550 consider ticking the answer then !